# ros node, ros driver and ros wrapper

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Im new to ros and am confused about what is the difference between ros node and ros driver? Because i saw some posts about ros wrapper for device with linux driver to make ros node.

Please explain . thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202000/ros-node,-ros-driver-and-ros-wrapper/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- A **ROS node** is any program that uses ROS to publish/subscribe to topics, calls or provides services etc. ROS nodes `#include` some ROS headers (C++) or `import` ROS modules (Python) and call functions defined there, like `ros::init()` / `rospy.init_node()`, `publish()` and so on. Some ROS nodes are "ROS drivers", others do path planning/sensor data processing/whatever.
- A **ROS driver** is a ROS node that makes a piece of hardware accessible from ROS. For example, it talks to a laser scanner and publishes the output of the device as ROS messages.
- Sometimes, the actual Linux hardware driver is part of the ROS driver node; however, it's better to separate the hardware driver and the ROS communication part. In that case, the Linux driver is usually provided as a ROS-agnostic library, and the ROS driver simply performs API calls to that library and converts the results to ROS messages. In that case, it is called a **ROS wrapper**.

As an example, the [sicktoolbox](http://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox) is a standalone Linux device driver library for SICK laser scanners. If you search the source code, you won't find any mention of ROS in the actual source files. The [sicktoolbox_wrapper](http://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox_wrapper) is a ROS package that contains several ROS nodes, for example `sicklms`. If you look at the source code ([sicklms.cpp](https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper/blob/indigo-devel/ros/sicklms/sicklms.cpp)), you can see that it's a ROS node that uses the sicktoolbox API (by calling `GetSickScan()`) and publishes the result as a ROS message, so it's a ROS wrapper:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
[...]
ros::init(argc, argv, "sicklms");
[...]
sick_lms.GetSickScan(range_values, intensity_values, n_range_values, n_intensity_values);
[...]
pub->publish(scan_msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-01-30**:
Thanks for the reply. Just another quick question, what is the meaning of n.param("my_param",i,40)? It does not explain clearly on the wiki.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-01-30**:
It looks for "my_param" on the parameter server and stores the value in `i`. If the param is not present, it stores 40 in `i`. (That's why the wiki says 40 is the default value; I think it's explained clearly there.)